# java basic about loop and boolean expression

Tags: java

I have some confusion with the following code:

```
class basic {
    boolean b = false;

    void m() {
        // what does it do and how does compiler interpret this
        if (!b) {
        }
        // what does it do and how does compiler interpret this
        if (b) {
        }
    }
}
```

so my doubt is what does this statement  `if(!b)` and `if(b)` represent.

What I mean to say is `if(b)` can be represented as `if( b == true )` which can be further written as `if( false == true )`.

Comment: Is false equal to true?

Answer (score 1):

If we do an `if` statement like this:

`if(b) {}` It will check to see if `b == true`.

And if we add an exclamation mark like this:

`if(!b) {}` It will check to see if `b == false`.

`!` stands for NOT.

Answer (score 0):

`if()` statement will look if the result in paranthesis is true. In that case it will enter in the next part.

If your b is false then

`if(!b)` means "if true equals to true".
`if(b)` means "if false equals to true".

Answer (score 0):

In boolean 
`if(boolean)` is a way of showing if(value is true)
`if(!boolean)` is a way of showing if(value is false)

It means that if value of b is true or false

`if(!b){}` this means: is b false.

`if(b){}` this means: is b true.

It is not comparing as `if(false == true)`

Answer (score 0):

The statement `if(boolean)` is equivalent to `if(boolean == true)`.  The statement `if(!boolean)` is equivalent to `if(boolean != true)`.

As a `boolean` only ever has two values `{true, false}` then `if(boolean != true)` is equivalent to `if(boolean == false)`.

On a side note; in Java, naming conventions dictate that classes are always in `PascalCase` so the class should be `Basic` rather than `basic`.